# The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters

Tags: visualforce

I have below code in my VF page named `All_Cases`.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myArticles}" var="article">
<a href="{!article.url}" title="{!article.Title}" class="sampleLink" onclick="openArticleSubtab('{!article.articleId}','{!article.nodeId}','{!article.Title}','{!article.caaskey}','{!article.caseId}'); return false;" id="articleId">{!article.Title}</a>
</apex:repeat>


function openArticleSubtab(articleId, nodeId, articleTitle, caaskey, caseId) {
            var artTitle = articleTitle;            
            var urlName = "{!$Label.Knowledge_Article_Viewer_URL}?caasKey="+ caaskey +"&nodeId="+nodeId+"&caseId="+caseId;
            console.log('urlName---'+urlName);               
              sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function openSubtab(result) {
                sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id , urlName, true, artTitle, null, openSuccess, null);                
              });         
      }
```

When I click on a link, onclick function openArticleSubtab is called and it opens a subtab which is working fine. But when I open the link in new tab via right click menu 'href' will be executed. But I get below error.

> The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.

Comment: Is it a compile error or a run time error? Do you get any sort of stack trace?

Comment: it's a runtime error and I don't see it everytime. It works fine for some links. And I don't see any stack trace.

Comment: Can you post your APEX code, where you are populating myArticles list?Chances are there your field name may contain _ at the end.

Comment: Does the URL end with `/`? I have seen this error message occur in that case.